# How to plot data from csv for specific date and time?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to plot data from a csv-file where the y-axis represents resistance and the x-axis time. But I dont want to plot all of the data, only the data that start at 2022-02-21 10:44:00 and end at 2022-02-21 10:54:00 Here's a sample of the data:

```
    timestamp               resistance
2022-02-21 10:44:35.792893  10460.5248
2022-02-21 10:44:35.822877  10460.5048
2022-02-21 10:44:35.842826  10460.48
2022-02-21 10:44:35.872597  10460.4776
2022-02-21 10:44:35.892827  10460.4512
2022-02-21 10:44:35.922595  10460.4288
```

Here is the code and i think it will work but i keep getting (TypeError: strptime() argument 1 must be str, not float), and i dont know how to fix it.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import csv
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime

dt_format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f'


data=pd.read_csv('data_keithley1.csv')
start = '2022-02-21 10:45:00.462227'
end = '2022-02-21 10:56:00.004844'

timestamps =list(map(lambda timestamps: datetime.strptime(timestamps, dt_format) , data['timestamp']))
values = list(data['resistance'])


start_index = timestamps.index(start)
end_index = timestamps.index(end)

sub_timestamps = timestamps[start_index : end_index]
sub_values = values[start_index : end_index]

plt.plot(sub_timestamps, sub_values, label='Motstand [ohm]')
plt.xlabel('time [hh:mm:ss]')
plt.ylabel('Mot [ohm]')
plt.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.35)
_, labels = plt.xticks()
plt.setp(labels, rotation=45)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You don't [convert your date times into datetime objects](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html). And if this is your actual data format in your file, you probably ended up with three instead of two columns in `data`. Have you checked that  `timestamp` contains what you think it contains?

Comment: `df.info()` tells you that you have two columns `timestamp` and `resistance`? This is a surprising outcome with your code and sample input. What are their dtypes?

Comment: You already [asked this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71310328/plot-data-from-csv-file-in-a-specific-interval) a few days earlier and it got closed. Do not just repost it to get an answer. Please read the help pages on how to improve your post and edit the first one to improve it. (Okay, on second thought, the error message seems to be slightly different now, but there's not much of a difference)

Answer (score 0):

You've almost got it. You have sliced the `timestamps` to your desired range:

```py
x_1=x['21/02/2022  10:44:36':'21/02/2022  10:45:36']
```

but did not sliced the `resistance` values. Here is an example of how to do that, assuming the following dummy dataset:

```
test.csv:
             timestamp  resistance
0  21/02/2022 10:44:00           0
1  21/02/2022 10:45:00           1
2  21/02/2022 10:46:00           2
3  21/02/2022 10:47:00           3
4  21/02/2022 10:48:00           4
5  21/02/2022 10:49:00           5
6  21/02/2022 10:50:00           6
7  21/02/2022 10:51:00           7
```

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = pd.read_csv('test.csv')
start = '21/02/2022 10:44:00'
end = '21/02/2022 10:49:00'

timestamps = list(data['timestamp'])
values = list(data['resistance'])

start_index = timestamps.index(start)
end_index = timestamps.index(end)

sub_timestamps = timestamps[start_index : end_index]
sub_values = values[start_index : end_index]

plt.plot(sub_timestamps, sub_values, label='Temperature [deg C]')
plt.xlabel('time [hh:mm:ss]')
plt.ylabel('Temp [deg C]')
plt.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.35)
_, labels = plt.xticks()
plt.setp(labels, rotation=45)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Also, please note you've parsed your timestamps with `dt_format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f'` although your dates are in the format of `%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S.%f`.

Comment: You are plotting strings, not datetime values. For various reasons, this is rarely the desired output.

Comment: when i run the code the plot that comes out is messed up, look at the post below for picture.

Comment: @Lotem Nadir: Suppose that I have 5000 Dates. I want to print only 5 Dates  in x-axis...How can I achieve that?

Comment: But all the values inside the graph....Because now when I print every 1000, the x-axis and y-axis labels, I get also values every 1000 inside the graph...

Answer (score 0):

```html
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import csv
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime

dt_format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f'


data=pd.read_csv('data_keithley1.csv')


timestamps =list(map(lambda timestamps: datetime.strptime(timestamps, dt_format) , data['timestamp']))
values = list(data['resistance'])



sub_timestamps = timestamps
sub_values = values

plt.plot(sub_timestamps, sub_values, label='Motstand [ohm]')
plt.xlabel('time [hh:mm:ss]')
plt.ylabel('Mot [ohm]')
plt.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.35)
_, labels = plt.xticks()
plt.setp(labels, rotation=45)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).